# Read and write device-register in Linux device driver?

Tags: io, linux-device-driver

First of all, this is my first attempt to do a driver for a Linux kernel, so if I'm totally wrong here, bare with me.

In my current project, we have added a new device on the board (FPGA), and I have now the task to write a driver for that device. (I took the task mainly because I want to learn, as a big challenge for me.)

After many hours on youtube I have managed to do a skeleton of a module at least, that can be inserted into the kernel:

```c
/* Match table for OF platform binding */
const struct of_device_id module_of_match[] = {
        { .compatible = "foo,testtest", },
        { /* end of list */},
};
MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(of, module_of_match);

static int module_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *file_p) {
    pr_notice("module_open is called\n");
    return 0;
}

static int module_release(struct inode *inode, struct file *file_p) {
    pr_notice("module_release is called\n");
    return 0;
}

static ssize_t module_write(struct file *file_p, const char __user *user_buffer, size_t count, loff_t *f_pos) {
    pr_notice("module_write is called\n");
    return 0;
}

static ssize_t module_read(struct file *file_p, char __user *user_buffer, size_t count, loff_t *f_pos) {
    pr_notice("module_read is called\n");
    return 0;
}

static int module_probe(struct platform_device *pdev) {
    int ret;
    void __iomem *base_addr;
    struct device *dev = &pdev->dev;
    struct resource *res;

    pr_notice("module_probe called...name: %s\n", pdev->name);
    res = platform_get_resource(pdev, IORESOURCE_MEM, 0);
    base_addr = devm_ioremap_resource(dev, res);
    if(IS_ERR(base_addr)){
        pr_err("module_probe: Error when calling devm_ioremap_resource\n");
        return -1;
    }
    ret = misc_register(&module_dev);
    if (ret) {
        pr_err("module_probe: Failed to register module_dev\n");
        return ret;
    }
    pr_notice("module_probe registered %s\n", &module_dev.name);

    return 0;
}

static int module_remove(struct platform_device *pdev)
{
    pr_info("module_remove called...\n");
    misc_deregister(&module_dev);
    return 0;
}

/* Driver operations */
struct platform_driver module_driver = {
        .probe = module_probe,
        .remove = module_remove,
        .driver = {
            .name = DRIVER_NAME,
            .owner = THIS_MODULE,
            .of_match_table = module_of_match
        },
};

/**
 * @brief Structure holding configure file operations
 */
static struct file_operations module_fops = {
        .owner = THIS_MODULE,                        ///< Owner of module
        .open = module_open,                        ///< Open function
        .release = module_release,                  ///< Release function
        .read = module_read,                        ///< Read function
        .write = module_write,                      ///< Write function
};

module_platform_driver(module_driver);

static struct miscdevice module_dev = {
    .minor = MISC_DYNAMIC_MINOR, // Allocate a dynamic minor number
    .name = DRIVER_NAME,
    .fops = &module_fops,
};
```

Device-tree node:

```
uart_dev: dev8@a0190000 {
            compatible = "foo,testtest";
            reg = <0x0 0xa0190000 0x0 0x10000>;
        };
```

But right now I'm a bit lost here.
I want to do is to be able use the register in the device, 0xa0190000, to read and write some values with the read and write functions.
I found some APIs to be able to get the resource of the device, **`devm_ioremap_resource()`**, but after this I'm lost.
How shall I be able to write/read the register based on the resource pointer?

Or is this the wrong approach?

Comment: After calling that API you will get a virtual address as `void __iomem *`, which can be supplied to the functions from io.h, such as `readl()`.

Comment: Thnx, I will give it a try today to see how it works!

Comment: Thanks 0andriy! It worked really good with readl and writel!

Answer (score 0):

As [0andriy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2511795/0andriy) commented, it worked fine to use `readl()` and `writel()` to read and write the registers:

```c
u32 reg;
reg = readl(base_addr);
pr_notice("Reg read: %d\n", reg);
writel(0xff,base_addr);
reg = readl(base_addr);
pr_notice("Reg read: %d\n", reg);
```